# Django, csv file with non-ascii text not readable in windows excel file

Tags: python, django, csv

Below are my current code (and I tried BOM_UTF8 too)

```
     csv = df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-16-le', date_format='%Y%m%d %H:%M %p')

     filename = 'order.csv'
     response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv', charset='utf-16-le')
     response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)
     response.write(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE)
     response.write(csv)

    return response
```

Non ascii characters are all broken in windows excel.

Very interesting.. frustrating not being able to solve this fast in 2020..

Comment: you could create minimal working code with example data which makes problem.

Comment: @furas good idea, i'll try to come up with that

Comment: How are you opening the CSV file in Excel? Don't double click to open. Have you tried opening Excel and using Data -> From Text ? This lets you specify the code page being used.